# Lamp Uninstall and Xampp

Tags: lamp, xampp

I installed lamp with this tutorial a while back: http://www.unixmen.com/install-lamp-with-1-command-in-ubuntu-1010-maverick-meerkat/

I have since decided it would be better to use the more full-featured Xampp. I installed Xampp successfully, but localhost still displays the default apache page. Apparently, I need to uninstall the lamp components individually to use Xampp. Any advice on how best to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to remove the following packages :

- libapache2-mod-auth-mysql
- phpmyadmin
- mysql-server
- mysql-server-
- mysql-server-core-
- apache2 and related modules
- libapache2-mod-php5

use `sudo apt-get purge <package_name>` to remove the packages.

The text below is grabbed from [**Ubuntu help documentation**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP):

> ### Starting over: How to remove the LAMP stack
>
> To remove the LAMP stack
>   remove the following packages:
>
> Note: This assumes you have no other programs that require any of
>   these packages. You might wish to simulate this removal first, and
>   only remove the packages that don't cause removal of something
>   desired.
>
> ```
> apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient15off libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl libpq5 mysql-client-5.0 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.0 php5-common php5-mysql
> ```
>
> To also remove the debconf data, use the purge option when removing.
>   To get rid of any configurations you may have made to apache, manually
>   remove the /etc/apache2 directory once the packages have been removed.

Comment: I've done everything that you've described as far as I can tell - still no luck. Any other thoughts or resources?

Comment: Good that you found the fix. If you found this answer helpful then mark it as answered. Thanks